# jQuery Phone Regex Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, format

I have jQuery Validation plugin on a page. When someone types the phone number into the form field, I want the validator to only recognize a certain format (ru):

```
+#(###)-###-##-##
or
+#-###-###-####
or
+#-###-###-##-##
or
+###########
```

I have this in .js file:

```
$.validator.addMethod('customphone', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\+d{1}(\d{3})\d{7}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid phone number");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({    
        rules: {
            phone: 'customphone'
        } ...
```

This is not working for me, does anyone see why? Or is there a better way to do this? :)

Comment: `d` matches `d` alphabet. You want `\d` to match digits. `)` need to escape to match closing brace

Comment: Also, it will only match a string of 11 digits

Comment: @gurvinder372 sry i missed. +#-###-###-##-## - that's right

Comment: It seems to me, [`/^\+(?:\d(?:\(\d{3}\)|-\d{3})-\d{3}-(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{4})|\d{11})$/`](https://regex101.com/r/yP0bZ6/2) should work for you best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following regex:

```
/^\+(?:\d(?:\(\d{3}\)|-\d{3})-\d{3}-(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{4})|\d{11})$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP0bZ6/3)

The regex you have `^\+d{1}(\d{3})\d{7}$` has `d` instead of `\d` (thus failing to match digits) and unescaped parentheses (thus the pattern did not match literal parentheses).

Breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `\+` - a literal `+` symbol
- `(?:\d(?:\(\d{3}\)|-\d{3})-\d{3}-(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{4})|\d{11})` - two alternatives:

  - `\d(?:\(\d{3}\)|-\d{3})-\d{3}-(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{4})`:

    - `\d` - a digit
    - `(?:\(\d{3}\)|-\d{3})` - either `(123)` like substring or `-123` substring
    - `-\d{3}` - a hyphen followed with 3 digits
    - `-` - a hyphen
    - `(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{4})` - 2 digits followed with a hyphen and 2 digits or 4 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{11}`  - 11 digits
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

> This is not working for me, does anyone see why? Or is there a better
>   way to do this? :)

There are a couple of issues with your code

1. As Tushar has pointed out, `d` will match only `d`, to match a digit you need `\d`
2. Your regex is not affording for many things including `(###)` and `-`

I guess you are looking for this regex

```
/^\+\d(\(\d{3}\)){0,1}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}$/g
```

It will match for

```
/^\+\d(\(\d{3}\)){0,1}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}$/g.test("+4(222)-33-33-33"); //true
/^\+\d(\(\d{3}\)){0,1}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}$/g.test("+4(222)-333-333-333"); //true
/^\+\d(\(\d{3}\)){0,1}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}$/g.test("+4(222)333333333"); //true
/^\+\d(\(\d{3}\)){0,1}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}$/g.test("+4333333333"); //true
```

Comment: It won't since you haven't escaped ( and) character

Comment: +88888888888 (11 symbols) - this is doesn't work. `/^\+\d(\(\d{3}\)){0,1}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}(\-){0,1}\d{2,3}$/g.test("+4333333333");` - there's only 10 symbols, I need 11. Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your javaScript but here is the different regex you have to check for.... I hope this helps.

```
+#(###)-###-##-##
^\+\d{1}\(\d{3}\)\-\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$
+#-###-###-####
^\+\d{1}\-\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$
+#-###-##-##
^\+\d{1}\-\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$
+###########
^\+\d{11}$
```

So I would setup a phone is valid flag and test each regex value to determine if  one of them is true set this flag to true and it would validate your phone number.

```
var phoneValid = false;

if(test1 == true || test2 == true || test3 == true || test4 == true) {
  phoneValid = true;
} else {
  phoneValid = false;
}
```